# Calculating Bayes factor

Tags: statistics, bayesian

*Example*: **Integer-valued** data $y = (y_1, ...,y_n):$

$M_1 = Geometric(\theta_1)$ likelihood with $Beta(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$ prior on $\theta_1;$

$M_2=Poisson(\theta_2)$ likelihood with $Gamma(\alpha_2, \beta_2)$ prior on $\theta_2$.

The **Bayes factor** in favor of $M_1$ over $M_2$ turns out to be

$$\large \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \beta_1)\Gamma(n +\alpha_1)\Gamma(n \bar{y} + \beta_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)(n + \beta_2)^{n\bar{y+\alpha_2}}(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n y_i !) }{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\beta_1)\Gamma(n+n\bar{y}+\alpha_1+\beta_1)\Gamma(n\bar{y}+\alpha_2)\beta^{\alpha_2}_2}$$

**Diffuse priors:** take $(\alpha_1, \beta_1)=(1,1)$ and $(\alpha_2, \beta_2)=(\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0.$

**Bayes factor** reduces to

$$\large \frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n \bar{y} + 1)\Gamma(\epsilon)(n+\epsilon)^{n\bar{y}+\epsilon}(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n y_i !) }{\Gamma(n + n\bar{y} +2)\Gamma(n\bar{y}+\epsilon)\epsilon^\epsilon}$$

The Bayes factor $\rightarrow +\infty$  depending on the value of $\epsilon$.

I was wondering if someone could explain this example step-by-step, and perhaps break down the calculations for me? Is this a proof already explained somewhere, if so could someone link me to it? Many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what you want help with? The Bayes factor and why it looks like it does? Or the end result (what the factor reduces to with diffuse priors)? Or the limit result in the end?